# modalpopup vs url rewriting

Tags: asp.net, ajax, url-rewriting, modalpopups

Why when i use url rewriting then modalpopup(asp.net ajax controltoolkit doesn't work?Why?

[my code](http://www.djkbf.hr/~atokic/fafa.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IIS rewrite module? If so you might find the Form.Action is the non-rewritten version of the page. Try setting the form action like this on your page's code behind:

```
Form.Action = Request.RawUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

I use UrlRewriting.dll  from  http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html